# Splitting open sets in perfect spaces

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $V$ is a Hausdorff space which is perfect and $U\subset V$ is a non-empty open set. Can we find two disjoint, non-empty open sets $U_1, U_2\subset U$? Is there any natural class of spaces having this property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure: just pick distinct $x,y\in U$, use the fact that $X$ is Hausdorff to choose disjoint open nbhds $V_x$ and $V_y$ of $x$ and $y$, respectively, and let $U_1=V_x\cap U$ and $U_2=V_y\cap U$.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Sure.

Comment: @usao: You’re welcome.